# Checking Offset of Kafka topic for a storm consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, offset, trident

I am using storm-kafka-client 1.2.1 and creating my spout config for KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque as below

```
            kafkaSpoutConfig = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(brokerURL, kafkaTopic)
                .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"storm-kafka-group")
                .setProcessingGuarantee(ProcessingGuarantee.AT_MOST_ONCE)
                .setProp(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
```

I am unable to find neither my group-id nor the offset in both Kafka and Zookeeper. Through Zookeeper I tried with zkCli.sh and tried `ls /consumers` but there were none as I think Kafka itself is now maintaining offsets rather than zookeeper.

I tried with Kafka too with the command below

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand  --list  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
console-consumer-20130
console-consumer-82696
console-consumer-6106
console-consumer-67393
console-consumer-14333
console-consumer-21174
console-consumer-64550
```

Can someone help me how I can find my offset and will it replay my events in Kafka again if I restart the topology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trident doesn't store offsets in Kafka, but in Storm's Zookeeper. If you're running with default settings for Storm's Zookeeper config the path in Storm's Zookeeper will be something like `/coordinator/<your-topology-id>/meta`.

The objects below that path will contain the first and last offset, as well as topic partition for each batch. So e.g. `/coordinator/<your-topology-id>/meta/15` would contain the first and last offset emitted in batch number 15.

Whether the spout replays offsets after restart is controlled by the `FirstPollOffsetStrategy` you set in the `KafkaSpoutConfig`. The default is `UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST`, which does not start over on restart. See the Javadoc at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.1/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig.java#L126.

Comment: I could find the offsets here -- by running command in ZkCli of storm `ls /transactional/<MYSpout>/coordinator/meta`  @Stig How can parallelise  consuming messages using Trident Storm from Kafka using topic partitions (=5)  ? Any Suggestion on increasing the throughput ?